# Django Azure AD get user info

Tags: django, azure-active-directory

I am currently using django-azure-ad-auth package for user authentication purpose. I wanted to retrieve user information too like displayName etc, How do I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using django-azure-ad-auth package which helps only for authentication purposes. You need to use API's likes [MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for getting the user information.

To use MS Graph with Python please follow [MS document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/python)

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, I was actually trying something like this: url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"          token = request.GET.get('id_token')                                                                                           
    data = requests.get(url,headers={'Authorization': 'Token '+ token}).  But it returns invalid   access  token. Do we have to send id_token generated by azure in the header?

Comment: If my understanding is correct you are using implicit flow you need to send id token to get access token.

Comment: How do we generate access token? because after authentication i receive id_token?

Comment: You can get access token from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#successful-response)

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you like this - but can you please take a look at my recent question about Django Azure AD integration (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043316/django-microsoft-ad-authentication)