# Django Microsoft AD Authentication

Tags: django, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, django-login

I noticed that this question was repeated few times, but still, from all the resources, I couldn't manage to make it work properly.

I'm simply trying to use Azure Active Directory authentication with my Django app.
I am using [this](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#redirect-based-authentication-flow) module, and I configured everything as noted in the docs.

The thing is - I can't figure out where should user enter the credentials - since the module has only
one url ('auth-callback/'). I can't find out how to jump to Microsoft login html page. Should I use my login.html or?

Also, I guess that 'auth-callback/' url is obviously a callback URL, which comes after the login page.

I am using django auth.views LoginView for login, and custom login.html page.

In terms of Redirect URI's I configured redirect URI to match directly the 'http://localhost:8000/microsoft/auth-callback/' url, which is also how it needs to be I guess.

Main problem is - where can I enter the credentials for login? :)

Also, when I try this - I get invalid credentials error on my Admin login page :

```
Start site and go to /admin and logout if you are logged in.
Login as Microsoft/Office 365/Xbox Live user. It will fail. This will automatically create your new user.
Login as a Password user with access to change user accounts.
```

Quick Edit :

I noticed that when i go to django/admin page '..../admin/login' inside the console i have this error :

```
https://static/microsoft/css/login.css Failed to load resource (404)
https://static/microsoft/js/login.js Failed to load resource (404)
```

Where can i get those files?

Let's jump to my code :

1. settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'microsoft_auth',
    ...
]

#Choped from templates
'context_processors': [
                ...
                'microsoft_auth.context_processors.microsoft',
            ],


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'microsoft_auth.backends.MicrosoftAuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]


SITE_ID = 1


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'main:index'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'main:index'

LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/'

# AZURE AUTH CONFIG
MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_ID = 'THIS IS MY CLIENT KEY'
MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET = 'THIS IS MY SECRET KEY'
MICROSOFT_AUTH_TENANT_ID = 'THIS IS MY TENANT KEY'

# include Microsoft Accounts, Office 365 Enterpirse and Azure AD accounts
MICROSOFT_AUTH_LOGIN_TYPE = 'ma'
```

And my urls.py

```
...
    path('microsoft/', include('microsoft_auth.urls', namespace='microsoft')),
...
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: See the issue: https://github.com/AngellusMortis/django_microsoft_auth/issues/471.

Answer (score -2):

django-microsoft-auth uses the standard django login page and extends that. My guess is that your custom login page is interfering with that. You could try removing that view and test again to see if the login appears at /admin.

The files should be coming from the django-microsoft-auth package. You could try uninstalling and reinstalling it again with pip

Comment: Sorry but this is not an answer to my problem - I already said i tried everything from the docs :)

Comment: And i noticed that the package doesn't get included by default into the templates